# "&" in "swap(&someInt, &anotherInt)". What does it represent? What is its function?

Tags: swift, inout

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to learn the concept of 'inout' keyword. I saw this code in "the swift programming language 2.1". My question is, why is there a "&" in "swap(&someInt, &anotherInt)". What does it represent? What is its function?

```
func swapTwoInts(inout a: Int, inout _ b: Int){
    let temporaryA = a
    a = b
    b = temporaryA
}

var someInt = 3
var anotherInt = 107
swap(&someInt, &anotherInt)

print("someInt is now \(someInt) and anotherInt is now \(anotherInt)")
```

Comment: In the *same section* of the Swift book: *"You place an ampersand (&) directly before a variable’s name when you pass it as an argument to an in-out parameter, to indicate that it can be modified by the function."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like passing by reference in C++, the ampersands in the calling bit of the code just tell the compiler that you give permission to function `swapTwoInts` to change both `someInt` and `anotherInt`. If you had not put the ampersands there, the code would not compile.

Comment: *"If you had not put the ampersands there, the value of both variables would not change after the swap function."* – No, then the code would not compile.

Comment: Indeed, since we need two inout variables.